# Plot Notes present in sound sample

Tags: sound, education

I would like to visualize a sampled sound, and place the sounds as notes starting from `C0` to `A8` or such. I have a table of frequencies (in $[Hz]$) of these notes, and I have a sample sound.

My goal is to have along the $y$ axis the possible notes, and along the $x$ axis the time.

My main question is, what are the values of the `SampleSoundList`, and can they easily be related to the frequencies from my table? The table is in *Excel*, but I could write it out as a list of `{ { C0, 16.35}, .. }`.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Additional Information: What are values?

```
toSpectrogram[x_] := Print[Spectrogram[x]] &&  Print[ x ]
Button["Sing", snd = SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]; 
 toSpectrogram[snd[[1]]], Appearance -> "DialogBox", 
 Method -> "Queued"]
```

What I mean by what are the values of a SampledSoundList in this sense:

```
SampledSoundList[{{0.,0.,-0.0078125,0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.0078125,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.0078125,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.0078125,0., ........ 0.,0.,0.0078125}},11025]
```

The final value ,11025] is the sample rate. But what are all of the other Reals? How could/would they relate to finding a pitch, or frame to look at to figure out if the sound is a note or what note they are?

Can I iterate over this list of "values" and get an idea of the Musical Note at any point, or series of points?

I imagine that the sound is sampled at a certain rate, i.e. the 11025 and so this means that a certain block of numbers in the list represent a point in time, but I don't know what the actual numbers mean? Are they some kind of representation of pitches?

The numbers are from -1 to 1, so they represent some kind of whole but what that whole is is unknown to me. I am sorry if I am being dense. This is just an area of curiosity for me.

Thanks

**EDIT**

From all the input and more doc reading, I have come up with this:

```
toSpectrogram[x_] := (Print[Spectrogram[x]]; plotSampledSoundList[x])
plotSampledSoundList[
  x_] := (sa = Abs[SpectrogramArray[x[[1]][[1]], 16, 10]]; 
  Print[ListLinePlot[sa[[{10, 35}]], DataRange -> {0, 8000}, 
    PlotRange -> {{500, 5000}}, Ticks -> {Automatic, None}]])
Button["Sing", snd = SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]; 
 toSpectrogram[snd[[1]]], Appearance -> "DialogBox", 
 Method -> "Queued"]
```

This is getting very close to what I want, though I am still unclear on some of the arguments. In the case of SpectrogramArray, the 16 is supposed to be the bit depth of the sample? So if I record at 11khrtz 16bit then this should be good? The plot that comes out is what I was hoping for, but I could be wrong.

The final part of my question is: How do I place the Note values up the y axis starting with C0-A8 or what not ( can be smaller range, or even better if it fits the sound to the range).

Comment: What do you mean "what are the values of `SampleSoundList`" ? I can easily ask what are the values of the traffic lights from here to Baltimore, but that would not make sense. Please, elaborate :) And also add any relevant data - even if it is a sample.

Comment: Look at `SpectrogramArray`, especially the "Neat Example"

Comment: I added some more details and some working code to look at what I am looking at.

Comment: @Simon Woods SpectrogramArray seems to be the right direction, but what is meant by partition, or more specifically, how do I figure out the partition?

Comment: The numbers in `SampledSoundList` are samples of the wave amplitude. You need to do some processing to convert this data to a time-frequency representation. One way is to split the data into chunks (partitions) and compute the discrete Fourier transform of each chunk, which is what `SpectrogramArray` does. The second argument is the length of each partition, i.e. the number of samples it contains.

Answer (score 4):

To help you get started, here is a simple demonstration with `Spectrogram`. First I need a list of note names and frequencies:

```
notes = Thread[{440.0*2^(Range[0, 12]/12),
         {"A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A"}}];
```

Now I choose a sample rate and generate a set of samples corresponding to playing each note in turn for 1/2 second. In your application you are getting the list of samples from the `SampledSoundList`.

```
samplerate = 20000;

samples = Join @@ Table[Sin[2 \[Pi] f t],
    {f, notes[[All, 1]]},
    {t, 0, 0.5, 1/samplerate}];
```

Now show the `Spectrogram`:

```
Show[Spectrogram[samples, 2048, 256, BlackmanWindow,
  DataRange -> {
    {0, Length[samples]/samplerate},
    {0, samplerate/2}},
  AspectRatio -> 0.8],
 PlotRange -> {All, {600, 700}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Range[0, 7], Range[400, 1000, 100], {}, notes},
 GridLines -> {None, notes[[All, 1]]},
 GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[0.3],
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
 FrameLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Frequency (Hz)", "", "Notes"}]
```

[image]